# Javascript replace character in regular expression in matched group

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to capture a matched group in a regular expression, and inside of that regular expression, inside of that matched group I need to replace a character AND duplicate the match. So for example

`foo-bar-baz`

I would need to do `/foo-(\w+)-baz/` but I would want to replace all 'r' in that matched group with a 't' and duplicate it so like

`foo-barbat-baz`

There could be multiple matches in the same string, so like `test-string-foo-bar-baz-another-foo-bar-baz` would become `test-string-foo-barbat-baz-another-foo-barbat-baz`

I know I can use `$1` .. etc in .replace but that doesn't handle an arbitrary amount of matches. I also know about `\n` (e.g. `\1`) and `\k` but none of these seem to help.

I've tried looping through the matches, but I can't figure out how to tell about the match position in the string, so I can 'insert' the replacement after it, and then once I replace it, the string length changes so the next match position wouldn't be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this lambda approach in `.replace`:

```js
const s = 'test-string-foo-bar-baz-another-foo-bar-baz';

var repl = s.replace(/(foo-)(\w+)(-baz)/g,
    (m, g1, g2, g3) => g1 + g2 + g2.replace(/r/g, "t") + g3);

console.log(repl);
```

**RegEx/lamnda Details:**

- `(foo-)(\w+)(-baz)`: Use 3 capture groups to capture `foo-` in 1st, `\w+` in 2nd and `-baz` in 3rd group
- `(m, g1, g2, g3)`: Makes available `m` (full match) and `gN` (Nth capture group) to lambda expression
- `g1 + g2 + g2.replace(/r/g, "t") + g3`: Concatenates `g1 + g2 + g3` while duplicating `g2` by replacing `r` with `t`

Comment: Nice, works also without `s` param in replace

Comment: I am working on it, as you can imagine this isn't quite my case but I am modifying my complex re to see if I can accomplish this with an arbitrary number of matches

Comment: `as you can imagine this isn't quite my case`: Sorry I don't get you. This does match your expected output and does exactly what you've asked in question. please clarify what is not working for you?

Comment: sorry this is exactly what I was asking for. What I meant is I need to adapt it to my code, and figure out my regular expression, as i'm not really searching for 'foo-bar-baz' but complex strings. I got it working last night, thanks for the help.

Comment: Good to know that you got it working but please understand an answer can only address a stated problem not something that hasn't been mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @anubhava i never suggested otherwise, but sometimes to ask a question it is better to simplify it rather than putting in a lot of complexity. it answered my question and i appreciate it very much.